# Parsing JSON with Snowflake SQL using flatten

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following code that creates a temp table from table with JSON data in columns.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table AS
(
    WITH 
    var1 AS (
        SELECT ts
            ,col1 AS details
        FROM raw_temp_table
            ,TABLE (flatten(input => $1,OUTER => TRUE)) var1
        )
    ,var2 AS (
        SELECT var1.ts
            ,col1 AS details
            ,details: "json_attr1" AS attr1
            ,details: "json_attr2" AS attr2
        FROM var1
            ,TABLE (flatten(input => $2,OUTER => TRUE)) var2
        WHERE KEY = 'some_key'  -- "some-key" is not a column in any of the tables, but it is an attribute in the JSON
        )
    SELECT * FROM var2
);
```

The json being parsed looks like this:

```json
{
    "json_attr1": "val1",
    "json_attr2": {
        "data": [{...}]
    }
}
```

I want to get the objects from the `data` array and either create a new table that holds them or somehow add them to the temp table as a column, as I will parse them in a new query.
I tried to add a new `var` but I don't know how to use the result. I am also interested in what exactly the `,TABLE(flatten(input => $2)) var2 WHERE KEY = "some_key"` part does, as I can't find any other examples of that.

Is there a way to add the `data` array to the table using that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if below query is serving the purpose for you.
Here I'm using lateral flatten which is more handy.

Flatten will simply unfold any nested objects and place them into separate row.

```
WITH fake_table as (
    select parse_json('{
            "json_attr1": "val1",
            "json_attr2": {
                "data": [{"nest1":"nestval1","nest2":"nestval2"}
                        ,{"nest1":"nestval3","nest2":"nestval4"}]
            }
        }') raw
    
) 
,var1 AS (
    SELECT l1.key l1_key,l2.key l2_key,l4.key l4_key,l4.value::varchar l4_value
    -- select l3.*
    FROM fake_table
        ,lateral flatten(input => raw) l1
        ,lateral flatten(input => l1.value) l2
        ,lateral flatten(input => l2.value) l3
        ,lateral flatten(input => l3.value) l4
    where l4_key = 'nest1'
    )
SELECT * FROM var1;
```